# Is this the OK scoped way to get random element from the container?

Tags: c++, templates, random, c++11

recently I decided to try out new c++11 random lib, and one thing came to mind... to get rid of the [rand()%nelemennts] when picking random element from container. Reason is that i want repeatable generation, when using rand encapsulation is nonexistant because

```
auto set_a=generateSet(nelements1); //generateSet calls rand
auto set_b=generateSet(nelements2); //so set_b is determined by the previous line :(
```

So this is what I came up with:
(note that this isnt thread safe, it is designed to be safe in a way that calls to generateSet dont affect eachother(through changing state of rand internal value))

```
template<typename container_type,typename element_type >
class RandElemGetter
{

    const container_type& containter_ref;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> distribution;
    std::mt19937 engine;
public:
    RandElemGetter(container_type& container): containter_ref(container),distribution(0,container.size()-1)
    {

    }
    element_type get()
    {
        return containter_ref[distribution(engine)];
    }
};
```

usage :

```
{
vector<int> v{1,2,3,1701,1729};
vector<int> result;
RandElemGetter<vector<int>,int> reg_v(v);
for(size_t i=0;i<nelements;++i)
result.push_back(reg_v.get());
}
```

So is this OK solution? I know it is not thread safe, that is not the point. Im wondering is there better  "scoped" way of getting random element from random access container. It could be modified maybe with std::advance to work for all.

Comment: I think this question is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If u remove the code it could be a question, I just wanted to give my answer in the Q so that I dont have to give my answer separately. It is a new feature(rand stuff in c++11) so I guess people will think of some nice way to do it.

Comment: A few comments: 1. Beware that your class can return the same element several times (I'm not sure if this is a desired behavior or not). So `result` in your sample may not contain all elements of `v`. 2. You don't need to pass the type of element, you can access it through `container_type::value_type` (note that using a trait would be better, but I'm not sure there is one in the standard library or in Boost). 3. Indeed, you could use iterators to accomodate more containers: you just need to use `container::begin` and `advance`.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is simply: Yes, this is an Ok solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
RandElemGetter(container_type container):
   containter_ref(container),distribution(0,container.size()-1)
```

This takes the container by value, creating a temporary copy, and stores a reference to that copy. The reference is invalid once the constructor has finished.

You need to either store a copy, or pass the argument by reference. It's a good idea to pass complex objects by constant reference anyway, to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: ouch... terrible bug, tnx, I noticed something is wrong, but I thought it was some optimization broken because i have pre release 4.6.0 :)

Answer (score 1):

- I would use `<typename container_type, typename value_type = container_type::typename value_type>`. STL containers have typedefs for their value_types, so there's usually no need to repeat yourself.
- The correct solution is indeed to return `*std::advance(containter_ref.begin(), distribution(engine));`
- I'd rename `get()` to `operator()`, and provide a `result_type` typedef to comply with the STL model [AdaptableGenerator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/AdaptableGenerator.html)

You might want to have a peak at SGI's `random_sample` from the original STL; I believe GNU still has that as an extension.

Comment: tnx, I will try the first 2 points now. Regarding typedef unfortunately I dont get what is it supposed to acomplish so I dont know how to implement it... Regarding random sample... I would geustimate it uses rand() and rand() I hate :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Don't guestimate; it accepts a RNG (STL concept: Generator).